# $http.get call error function from success

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-promise

I do not have the ability to change an endpoint, and it will return a 200 OK response with different data if it fails. How can I make it run the error function (The 2nd function in a `then` from a promise)?

MyService service:

```
self.getData = function() {
    return $http.get('/api/controller/action').then(function(x) {
            //This will be run even on failure. How can I call....
            return x.data;
        }, function(x) {
            //......here, from the front-end, so that, the 2nd function in
            //inside the 'then' in the controller is run.
            //This code will currently never run as it never fails server side.
            return x;
        });
};
```

controller:

```
MyService.getData().then(function(x) {
    //Success
}, function(x) {
    //Failure
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `$q.reject`, eg

```
return $http.get('/api/controller/action').then(function(x) {
    if (x.data === 'some error condition') {
        return $q.reject(x);
    }
```

Comment: Will it execute `$httpInterceptor` responseError function if I used interceptors?

Comment: @JayShukla No as that happens before the promise is resolved. You can implement the rejection of the otherwise successful HTTP response from the interceptor though

Comment: Very clever. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can also check status of response you are getting after hitting the API ,
like, means there is some problem in API

if(status!=200){

// do something

}